# Creating deb or rpm with setuptools – data_files

Tags: python, python-3.x, rpm, setuptools, deb

I have a Python 3 project.

```
MKC
├── latex
│   ├── macros.tex
│   └── main.tex
├── mkc
│   ├── cache.py
│   ├── __init__.py
│   └── __main__.py
├── README.md
├── setup.py
└── stdeb.cfg
```

On install, I would like to move my latex files to known directory, say `/usr/share/mkc/latex`, so I've told `setuptools` to include data files

```
data_files=[("/usr/share/mkc/latex",
             ["latex/macros.tex", "latex/main.tex"])],
```

Now when I run

```
./setup.py bdist --formats=rpm
```

or

```
./setup.py --command-packages=stdeb.command bdist_deb
```

I get the following error:

```
error: can't copy 'latex/macros.tex': doesn't exist or not a regular file
```

Running just `./setup.py bdist` works fine, so the problem must be in package creation.

Comment: Do you have a repository of this online somewhere; perhaps on [Github](https://github.com)?

Comment: https://github.com/pacholik/MKC

Answer (score 12, accepted):

When creating a deb file (I guess the same counts for a rpm file), `./setup.py --command-packages=stdeb.command bdist_deb` first creates a source distribution and uses that archive for further processing. But your LaTeX files are not included there, so they're not found.

You need to add them to the source package. Such can be achieved by adding a [MANIFEST.in](https://packaging.python.org/en/latest/distributing.html#manifest-in) with contents:

```
recursive-include latex *.tex
```

[distutils](https://docs.python.org/3/distutils/setupscript.html#installing-additional-files) from version 3.1 on would automatically include the `data_files` in a source distribution, while [setuptools](https://pythonhosted.org/setuptools/setuptools.html#generating-source-distributions) apparently works very differently.

Comment: It's working and I think I know why. The bounty is yours!